# Coin Toss System

Tags: probability, probability-theory

http://www.quantwolf.com/calculators/recurrencetime.html

The expected number of runs for 2 consecutive heads or tails is 3.
Is there an edge if we place a progressive bet of consecutive appearance of H or T only after pattern HTH or THT appears? Or is prob=0.5 always?

Comment: why is the link there?

Answer (score 1):

The probability is allways 0.5. This is independent of the previous pattern.